# tranquility kafka data to Druid Server

Tags: apache-kafka, druid, data-ingestion

I setup a druid cluster,the OVERLORD and COORDINATER ui are all worked.every nodes can also be launched and no errors. I test it by quickstart batch,it worked. Now I would like to use tranquility to ingestion kafka data,when I ran "bin/tranquility kafka -configFile conf/kafka.json" command,the result is below:

[image]

but the data cannot be saved hdfs and there is no task in the OVERLORD and COORDINATER ui,how can i location the bugs and fix them?

Below is my cluster:

> broker:2 nodes
>
> Coordinator:2 nodes
>
> Overlordad:2 nodes
>
> Historical:3nodes
>
> Middle Manager:3nodes

broker,Coordinator,Overlordad are setuped on all same 2 nodes,Historical and Middle Manager are setuped on all same 3 nodes.

Comment: Can you please share some logs? Looks like the problem can be in multiple places - kafka reading, errors in druid ingestion, etc.

Comment: had been solved,thank you above all